# Get I/O errors on USB ports

Tags: linux-mint, usb

I have a program written in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8 under Mint 13.  One of the modules pulls data off a number of USB devices for subsequent analysis. Everything works fine with Dell laptops but when installed on the HP 255 G1 ~40% of them report USB I/O errors, all ports are USB 2.0

One suggestion made to me was to try booting via USB with Mint 17 to see if there are any updates included that resolve the problem. Whilst booting with Mint 17 is not a problem I could not see the program as the only directory under /home is 'mint'. I then put a copy of the software in /home/mint but found that although Mint 17 includes Python it does not appear to include wxPython.

I am somewhat unsure where to go next. Can I drop wxPython into the Mint 17 boot; are there other diagnostics I could run; could there be a driver update as I have seen many times on Windowz; etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can install wxPython in the USB booted Mint 17 with the following commandline:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n
```

If you need additional packages that are on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/) you might as well directly add `python-pip` as a third package on that line, so later you can do, e.g.:

```
pip install libusb1
```

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install python-wxtools wx2.8-i18 but it came back with 'cannot resolve archive.ubuntu.com' so still in the same place...

Comment: @MichaelJohn you normally only get that message if you are not connected to the internet, aren't you? No DHCP server on your network that provides nameserver info?

Comment: You were right the WiFi connection does not work with the USB boot so I had tio quickly sort out a cable! However after loading wxPython, and pythgon-usb and python-scipy, although my software then ran it could not see the USB devices The debug said it failed to claim the interface 001.015 and therefore failed to connect,,,